# Position of data label in bar graph using C# (interop)

Tags: c#, bar-chart, excel-interop

I have a bar chart that I generate dynamically. I have used a tricky fix to show datalabel above the series. I use two graphs, setting fill property of one of them to none. Then I set the datalabel of this invisible graph to "Inside Base". Thus I can set the ranges of both graphs to same selection and display same data.

The issue I am facing is that when the length of datalabel exceeds the length of corresponding bar, the label tends to shift left and go outside the plot area. Due to this, the data label appears clipped from left.

Is there a way by which I can set the position of datalabels of a bar graph relative to the plot area? Like setting the left of datalabel to  parent.Position.Left  +10 ?

Comment: This sounds more like an Excel problem than a c# problem correct?

Comment: No idea! If there is a way to set the position of datalabel in C#, it might work for me. Although I agree that in terms of tools I use, problem might be with excel.

Comment: Can you manually adjust the chart so the graph is properly viewable?

Comment: Yes. I can do it manually through excel.

Comment: Are you using interop's ChartObject to create the chart?

Comment: Yes I am using ChartObject.Chart.SetSourceData() function for this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37138/discussion-between-paqogomez-and-pankaj)

Comment: As a side note, you should read the question [Should questions include tags in their titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) where the consensus is, no, they should not.

Answer (score 1):

Based on our chat conversation, the problem is that the excel file needs to be refactored to hold larger data on the data labels.

Comment: Well, I tried refactoring the excel sheet to accommodate large strings for data labels. Now when the length is small for a data label, that data label shifts to right and formatting does not look good. Thanks for your suggestion though, now I know what the exact cause is.

Comment: how about 2 excel templates, one for small data and one for large.  Please dont forget to select the answer and/or upvote if this was helpful.

Comment: What else are you running into?  Can I help?

Comment: Hey.. I tried fixing this, What I did is that I set the label length to 35 characters in the excel template. Then during generation of data at runtime, I set the length of the data to be displayed in labels to 35, either by appending spaces or by clipping the string to 35 characters. Now the issue is that appending spaces does not make the visible length of two strings equal.